# Pointwise convergence of $f_n(x)=\cos(2n\pi\, x)x^{2n}$ on the interval $[-1,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, convergence-divergence

Pointwise convergence of $f_n(x)=\cos(2n\pi\, x)x^{2n}$ on the interval $[-1,1]$ ?

I think it must converge to $f(x)=0$ but how can I show this? This function does not converge uniformly right? I think I was able to prove that. Please a hint, or even a yes/no response would be great, thanks.

Comment: The point wise doesn't exist either. At the point $-1$, the pointwise sequence is $(-1)^n$, which is not convergent. All right, I saw the edit.

Comment: very sorry, i posted the wrong function

Comment: with $x^{2n}$ does this change things?

Comment: $x^{2n}$ does fix the issue.

Comment: Certainly it does. Now, the limit exists, and is $1$ at the end points and $0$ in the middle. The convergence isn't uniform, as the limit function is not continuous.

Comment: but not uniformly correct?

Comment: great thanks guys!

Comment: It does not converge at the point x=-1.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $|\cos(x)|\le 1$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Can you use this to show the pointwise convergence to $0$ for $x\in(-1,1)$? (Consider $|f_n(x)|$ for fixed $x$). What if $x=\pm 1$? (Does $f_n(x)$ still converge to $0$?)

As for uniform convergence, it may be worth thinking about $x^n$ on the interval $[0,1]$. This is a somewhat standard example of a sequence of functions that converges pointwise but not uniformly.

Comment: again very sorry, i posted the wrong function, please see the edit

Comment: My answer should still hold.

Let me know if I can clarify, or if you want more detailed hints.

Comment: I dont agree with your argument actually b/c we are on the interval $[-1,1]$

Comment: Clearly if we were dealing with the original function your answer would not be true, and that is what you based it off of because the sequence $a_n=(-1)^n$ does not converge...

Comment: You are assuming that $f_n(x)$ converges to $0$ everywhere. This is not true.

My answer was written with respect to the current function, not the original.